# rails db:migrate is aborting giving some bcrypt error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i cloned micheal hartl code at https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed and i tried running rails db:migrate but its giving me error

```
C:\Sites\sample_app_reference>rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.3/bcrypt_ext
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

there is my the error code, i'll like to know why it wasn't working

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: What does `C:/Sites/sample_app_reference/Rakefile:4:` look like? Looks like it's trying to load `bcrypt_ext` which it can't - guessing it has a syntax error or is missing altogether?

Comment: This might also help you https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Comment: i have run bundle install, it still didnt fix it

Answer (score -1):

Try instructions here:  https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142#issuecomment-252508115

> I solve it with uninstall all `bcrypt` gem versions with `gem uninstall
>   bcrypt` and select option 3 (if exist) and uninstall all `bcrypt-ruby`
>   gem versions with `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and select option 3 (if
>   exist) then install `bcrypt` using `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`
>   then add this line `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby` to `Gemfile`, that is
>   it :D.

Comment: i tried it, it didn't still work i did the exert instruction above and it told me instilled, but after running rails test, its still giving bcrypt error

Comment: Can you post your `application.rb` file?